# Distance between array of array

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have the following scenario:

```
public class World{
  public City[,] cities { get; set; }
}


public class City
{
    public int number_city { get; set; }        
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    public World world { get; set; }
    public Slot[,] slots { get; set; }
}

public class Slot
{
    public City city { get; set; }

    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
}
```

That is, it functions as a chess field, I have the object world with several cities and each city has a number of slots. The slots in each city are arranged in a grid, and each city's grid has the same number of rows and columns.

With this method I can get the distance between the Slots of the same city:

```
public static double GetDistance(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1)
{
    int dX = y1 - y0;
    int dY = x1 - x0;
    return Math.Sqrt(dX * dX + dY * dY);
}
```

Only I need to get the distance between slots of different cities

In each city the positions of the slots starts at zero, so I can not use them directly for calculating between cities.

There is no need for distance between worlds.

World (A world has several cities)

[image: Worlds]

City and slot

[image: City and slot]

I need for example the distance between the yellow PCs, the result would be 7

Comment: `GetDistance(city1.x + slot1.x, city1.y + slot1.y, city2.x + slot2.x, city2.y + slot2.y)`?

Comment: No :(
City city1 = new City();
city1.number_city = 1;
city1.x = 5;
city1.y = 5;

Slot slot1 = new Slot();
slot1.x = 3;
slot1.y = 4;


City city2 = new City();
city2.number_city = 2;
city2.x = 5;
city2.y = 6;

Slot slot2 = new Slot();
slot2.x = 3;
slot2.y = 4;

var x = UtilShared.GetDistance( city1.x + slot1.x, city1.y + slot1.y, city2.x + slot2.x,  city2.y + slot2.y);

x return 1, When should return 7,I will try to add images, to explain better

Comment: The tag `complexity-theory` doesn't help here, that's something different.

Comment: Which tag do you think is best? I can not think of any other.

Comment: It was kind of implied that coordinates in both `City` and `Slot` were in the same units. As they are not (because otherwise you have overlapping cities), you cannot do anything with them unless you bring them to the same unit, e.g. by declaring one city distance unit is 10 slot units and introducing `city1.x * 10 + slot1.x` into the formula. It's 5th grade geometry rather than programming.

Comment: I believe that it is no use to perform this type of operation to change all the X and Y axes an entire matrix is just a reference with different values.

I'm working on a new solution, I'm trying to recreate a new array "in the same medication unit as you said", then apply the distance algorithm.

I'm picking up the array slot and trying to add within the array's city location (extending the array of the world, so to say, so that it becomes only one).

That way I jam the X and Y of the slot to its new position.

Comment: You don't change the values in the matrix. You multiply by something when you calculate the distance.

Comment: Do all cities have the same size grid? I.e. they are all 7x7? And what does @GSerg mean when he says the coordinates differ and if they did not you would have overlapping cities? Assuming the cities all have the same size grid, then you just need to convert the "city coordinate" values used for slots to "world coordinates", which you do simply by adding the city's x/y values multiplied times 7 to the slot's "city coordinate" value. If that assumption's not correct, you need to provide more detail.

Comment: I did it this way: [https://dotnetfiddle.net/5d9N26](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5d9N26)
But it only works for elements on the right side of the current city. I'll have to make code changes for every possible direction in the array (right, down, down, up, and diagonals). @PeterDuniho, cities can not be overlapped, they are aligned according to the image of the world

Comment: @PeterDuniho I do not know if I understood your question very well, but the problem of assigning a common multiplier is that you imagine neighboring cities, the distance between the last element of the first city and the first element of the second city is only 1

example
[http://pastebin.com/raw/68Y5uv3b](http://pastebin.com/raw/68Y5uv3b)

Comment: _" the distance between the last element of the first city and the first element of the second city is only 1"_ -- why is that a problem? In your example, city #1 presumably has coordinates (0,0), while city #2 has coordinates (1,0). In that example, 3x3 cities mean the world coordinates for slot A are (0*3+2,0*3+0)=(2,0) and W for slot B are (1*3+0,0*3+0)=(3,0). Distance between (2,0) and (3,0) is 1, just like you want. What's the problem?

Comment: Likewise (same example), W for C is (0*3+1,0*3+2)=(1,2), W for D is (1*3+1,0*3+2)=(4,2), and distance between (1,2) and (4,3) is 3, again just like you want.

Comment: perfect @PeterDuniho thank you....
It was precisely this "secret", to multiply the size of the daughter matrix to each axis of the parent matrix, to generate a new matrix and to calculate the distance

Comment: great...glad it worked for you. I wrote up an answer based on the comments here, presented in a way that should be useful to future readers who want a more conceptual description of the solution.

Comment: I'll leave my test here too: [https://dotnetfiddle.net/kcyOST](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kcyOST)

Comment: @PeterDuniho I meant that in the [OP's example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613843/distance-between-array-of-array#comment72357308_42613843) the two cities are at `[5,5]` and `[5,6]`. If they are `7x7` each, they overlap, so apparently distances for cities are not in the same unit of measurement as distances for slots. [Your code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42618599/11683) does exactly what [I suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613843/distance-between-array-of-array#comment72358362_42613843) (which is not surprising, because what else can you do here).

Comment: @GSerg Really, had not realized, Peter's examples became simpler to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your clarification posted in the comments, I have edited your question to better reflect the scenario. You have `City` objects that occupy the `World`. Each `City` has an X/Y coordinate within the `World`, and contains `Slot` objects that have X/Y coordinates within the `City`. Each `City` is the same size, i.e. has the same number of rows and columns, and within the world each `City` is exactly adjacent to its neighbors. I.e. no gaps, no overlap, no odd-sized cities, etc.

Given that, your problem is easily solved once you treat it as a simple frame-of-reference problem. That is, while the `Slot` coordinates are relative to the `City` in which the `Slot` is contained, they still exist within the `World`. Borrowing a concept from physics or computer graphics, both of which have "frames of reference", where coordinates in one frame of reference can be mapped to another frame of reference with a simple transformation, we can apply this concept to your problem.

In particular, you can convert a `Slot`'s X/Y coordinates from a `City` frame of reference to a `World` frame of reference simply by multiplying the `City` X/Y coordinates by the width and height of a single city, and then adding to that the `Slot` X/Y coordinates:

```
struct SlotPoint
{
    public readonly int X;
    public readonly int Y;

    public SlotPoint(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x; Y = y;
    }
}

const int _kcityWidth = 7;
const int _kcityHeight = 7;

SlotPoint ConvertCityToWorld(Slot slot)
{
    return new SlotPoint(
        slot.city.x * _kcityWidth + slot.x, slot.city.y * _kcityHeight + slot.y);
}
```

With this transformation available, it's simple to calculate the distance between any two slots:

```
double GetDistance(Slot slot1, Slot slot2)
{
    SlotPoint point1 = ConvertCityToWorld(slot1), point2 = ConvertCityToWorld(slot2);

    return GetDistance(point1.X, point1.Y, point2.X, point2.Y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question properly that should do the trick:

```
 public static double GetDistance(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1)
        {
            // mirror image dictionary to manipulate the parallel columns
            Dictionary<int, int> mirrorMatrixCols = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            mirrorMatrixCols.Add(0, 7);
            mirrorMatrixCols.Add(1, 8);
            mirrorMatrixCols.Add(2, 9);
            mirrorMatrixCols.Add(3, 10);
            mirrorMatrixCols.Add(4, 11);
            mirrorMatrixCols.Add(5, 12);
            mirrorMatrixCols.Add(6, 13);

            var result = 0;
            // the distance of cells to the point of y1 column
            result = (x1 - x0) * 7;
            // add the distance to the manipulated column
            result = result + (mirrorMatrixCols[y1] - y0);
            return result;    
        }
```